# JTattoo look and feel Java - What's happening exactly?

Tags: java, netbeans, look-and-feel, palette

I downloaded JTattoo.jar for the look and feel of my application. However I am confused, is the look-and-feel concept a run-time issue (I will only see the JTattoo look and feel when I run the application but not on the Designer)?? or can I have the components added in the Palette so I can drag and drop the components??

Can you provide me with info to work with libraries other than Swing and have more desktop items in the Palette??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The look and feel will be applied  in run time rather than design time because IDE doesn't support that in design time naively.

If you mean you need swing components with external functionality try [SwingX](http://swinglabs.org/)

Moreover you can add swingx components (or any other component library) to netbeans designer for example by following these steps:

Go to the Palette Manager (Tools → Palette → Swing/AWT Components), click New Category…, name it SwingX, click Add from Library…, and select the SwingX library that you created in step 3. Activate all the components (Ctrl-A), choose the SwingX category, and you’re done!